# document.getElementbyID reference is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
let start=document.getElementById("start")

function intro(){
    start.hidden=true
}
```

When I use the start in function the code isn't working but when I use document.getElementById("start") instead of start the code works Perfectly

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: The dom may not have initialised at the point where you're calling getElementById. 
Try adding a defer to you script tag or assigning start inside of a window on load.